# Laravel DataTable plugin is outputting code with htmlentities

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using this [DataTable](https://packagist.org/packages/openskill/datatable) plugin for Laravel, which is for using This [jQuery DataTable](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) plugin.

I Followed the instructions found [here](http://openskill.github.io/Datatable/basic-usage/), so this is my controller:

```
class FeedbackController extends Controller {

    public function UserFeedback(Request $request) {
        $t = Datatable::make(new CollectionProvider(FeedbackModel::all()))
            ->column('overall')
            ->build();

        if ($t->shouldHandle()) {
            return $t->handleRequest();
        }

        return view('admin.feedback', ['datatable' => $t->view()]);
    }

}
```

And this is in my view:

```
{{
    $datatable->html()
}}
```

But for some reason when I load the page it is outputting the html with htmlentities like this:

```
&lt;table id=&quot;dataTable&quot;&gt;
    &lt;/table&gt;&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // dynamic table
        oTable = jQuery(&#039;#dataTable&#039;).DataTable({
            &quot;processing&quot;: true,
            &quot;serverSide&quot;: true,
            &quot;ajax&quot;: &quot;/&quot;,
            &quot;columns&quot;: [
                                { &#039;data&#039;: &#039;overall&#039; },
                            ]
        });
    });
&lt;/script&gt;
```

Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you (taken from laravel docs)

**Displaying Raw Text With Curly Braces**

If you need to display a string that is wrapped in curly braces, you may escape the Blade behavior by prefixing your text with an @ symbol:

`@{{ This will not be processed by Blade }}`

If you don't want the data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

`Hello, {!! $name !!}.`

Use that on this...

```
{{
    $datatable->html()
}}
```

> Ignore the above, that is the wrong way around, do the below...

**Or**

You can decode the html like this...

`htmlspecialchars_decode($datatable->html())`

and output that...